# Postgresql change column to row in a generic way

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab, unnest

A key value pair(column name, value) needs to be retrieved from a table with about hundred columns.

The following query does exactly what is needed.

```
With dummy AS (
    Select 1 as Col1, 2 as Col2
)
SELECT
   unnest(array['Col1', 'Col2']) AS "Column Name",
   unnest(array[Col1, Col2]) AS "Value"
FROM dummy
```

But, it requires to specify the columns explicitly.

Is there a way to generate the same output by not specifying the column names directly at all or generate it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, within limits. See the [`crosstab` function in the `tablefunc` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html).

It's not as nice as a real native `CROSSTAB` or `PIVOT` command, but it'll do the job.